# JIRA: how to have many Kanban boards for one project

Tags: jira, tasks, task-management

Here is the situation:
I have one project with several issues relating to tasks our team has to complete. We (currently) have two "categories" of tasks to complete. Let's call them: "Environment Setup" and "Technical Debt Removal". I want a way to track whether tasks are completed, and who is working on what.

I have issues in my project that either relate to one or the other, not both.

I would like to have two separate Kanban boards to track the work on these two things independently.

How do I do this?

I have tried to create several boards within the project but this doesn't work, since all the issues show up in both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What field are you entering the categories into? I would recommend using "component" (but using label or epic would also work) and then creating either quick filters or swimlanes for the 2 different components. This way they would live on the same board, but you can easily switch between quick filters to see only 1 category at a time.

But if you have your heart set on 2 different boards, you can easily do that also by changing the board configuration filter query. (Under General > Filter > Saved Filter > Edit Filter Query. JQL would be "component = Environment Setup". Then create a new board, with "component = Technical Debt Removal".

Comment: +1 For the solid answer, you might want to mention that components need to be set up at the project level and there are none by default. They have to be added under project admin.